# Is the script I ran malicious?

Tags: windows, security

I ran the script below hastily, and now I am afraid my laptop is compromised. How can i confirm my data is good.?

What data will they be able to get from this? can someone help me??

Warning:: please not execute below line:

I executed: `powershell iex (irm 'https://hotgames[dot]gg/genshin/get_wish_url.ps1')`

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, this script makes no changes to your computer. It attempts to read some (gacha) information from the *Genshin Impact* log files and/or its embedded browser’s cache storage.

It also does not upload any information elsewhere.

---

As you already appear to be aware, you should not just run scripts from the internet. Instead, download it and closely scrutinize its contents: Is it obfuscated or you don’t understand it *100%*? Don’t run it. If it appears to make changes that are unrelated to its stated purpose, also don’t run it. If it uploads data somewhere, …

Only run scripts you could have written yourself (given enough time and research) or that are from trusted sources (Microsoft, your employer and the like).

It’s not possible to reliably determine a system is clean. Once you have lost confidence, check out the [*How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?*](https://superuser.com/q/100360/219095) canonical question.

---

This is the script I got when downloading the URL:

```
# script version 0.11
# author: jogerj


function processWishUrl($wishUrl) {
    # check validity
    if ($wishUrl -match "https:\/\/webstatic") {
        if ($wishUrl -match "hk4e_global") {
            $checkUrl = $wishUrl -replace "https:\/\/webstatic.+html\?", "https://hk4e-api-os.mihoyo.com/event/gacha_info/api/getGachaLog?"
        } else {
            $checkUrl = $wishUrl -replace "https:\/\/webstatic.+html\?", "https://hk4e-api.mihoyo.com/event/gacha_info/api/getGachaLog?"
        }
        $urlResponseMessage = Invoke-RestMethod -URI $checkUrl | % {$_.message}
    } else {
        $urlResponseMessage = Invoke-RestMethod -URI $wishUrl | % {$_.message}
    }
    if ($urlResponseMessage -ne "OK") {
        Write-Host "Link found is expired/invalid! Open Wish History again to fetch a new link" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        return $False
    }
    # OK
    Write-Host $wishURL
    Set-Clipboard -Value $wishURL
    Write-Host "Link copied to clipboard, paste it back to paimon.moe" -ForegroundColor Green
    return $True
}

$logPathGlobal = [System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\miHoYo\Genshin Impact\output_log.txt");
$logPathChina = [System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow\miHoYo\$([char]0x539f)$([char]0x795e)\output_log.txt");
$globalExists = Test-Path $logPathGlobal;
$cnExists = Test-Path $logPathChina;

if ($globalExists) {
    if ($cnExists) {
        # both exists, pick newest one
        if ((Get-Item $logPathGlobal).LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Item $logPathChina).LastWriteTime) {
            $logPath = $logPathGlobal;
        } else {
            $logPath = $logPathChina;
        }
    } else {
        $logPath = $logPathGlobal;
    } 
} else {
    if ($cnExists) {
        $logPath = $logPathChina;
    } else {
        Write-Host "Cannot find Genshin Impact log file! Make sure to run Genshin Impact and open the wish history at least once!" -ForegroundColor Red
        if (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) {  
            Write-Host "Do you want to try to run the script as Administrator? Press [ENTER] to continue, or any key to cancel."
            $keyInput = [Console]::ReadKey($true).Key
            if ($keyInput -ne "13") {
                return
            }
            $arguments = "& '" +$myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
            Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "-noexit $arguments $reg"
            break
        } 
        return
    }
}


$logs = Get-Content -Path $logPath
$regexPattern = "(?m).:/.+(GenshinImpact_Data|YuanShen_Data)"
$logMatch = $logs -match $regexPattern

if (-Not $logMatch) {
    Write-Host "Cannot find Genshin Impact path in log file! Make sure to run Genshin Impact and open the wish history at least once!" -ForegroundColor Red
    pause
    return
}

$gameDataPath = ($logMatch | Select -Last 1) -match $regexPattern
$gameDataPath = Resolve-Path $Matches[0]

# Method 1
$cachePath = "$gameDataPath\\webCaches\\2.15.0.0\\Cache\\Cache_Data\\data_2"
if (Test-Path $cachePath) {
    $tmpFile = "$env:TEMP/ch_data_2"
    Copy-Item $cachePath -Destination $tmpFile
    $content = Get-Content -Encoding UTF8 -Raw $tmpfile
    $splitted = $content -split "1/0/" | Select -Last 1
    $found = $splitted -match "https.+?game_biz=hk4e_(global|cn)"
    Remove-Item $tmpFile
    if ($found) {
        $wishUrl = $Matches[0]
        if (processWishUrl $wishUrl) {
            return
        }
    }
    Write-Host "Retrying using fallback method..." -ForegroundColor Red
}

# Method 2 (Credits to PrimeCicada for finding this path)
$cachePath = "$gameDataPath\\webCaches\\2.15.0.0\\Service Worker\\CacheStorage\\f944a42103e2b9f8d6ee266c44da97452cde8a7c"
if (Test-Path $cachePath) {
    Write-Host "Using Fallback Method (SW)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    $cacheFolder = Get-ChildItem $cachePath | sort -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | select -First 1
    $content = Get-Content "$($cacheFolder.FullName)\\00d9a0f4d2a83ce0_0" | Select-String -Pattern "https.*#/log"
    $logEntry = $content[0].ToString()
    $wishUrl = $logEntry -match "https.*#/log"
    if ($wishUrl) {
        $wishUrl = $Matches[0]
        if (processWishUrl $wishUrl) {
            return
        }
        
    }
    Write-Host "Fallback Method (SW) failed to find wish history URL! Retrying using second fallback method..." -ForegroundColor Red
}

# Method 3
Write-Host "Using Fallback method (CCV)" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$cachePath = "$gameDataPath\\webCaches\\2.15.0.0\\Cache\\Cache_Data"
$tempPath = mkdir "$env:TEMP\\paimonmoe" -Force
# downloads ChromeCacheView
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chromecacheview.zip" -OutFile "$tempPath\\chromecacheview.zip"
Expand-Archive "$tempPath\\chromecacheview.zip" -DestinationPath "$tempPath\\chromecacheviewer" -Force
& "$tempPath\chromecacheviewer\\ChromeCacheView.exe" -folder $cachePath /scomma "$tempPath\\cache_data.csv"
# processing cache takes a while
while (!(Test-Path "$tempPath\\cache_data.csv")) { Start-Sleep 1 }
$wishLog = Import-Csv "$tempPath\\cache_data.csv" | select  "Last Accessed", "URL" | ? URL -like "*event/gacha_info/api/getGachaLog*" | Sort-Object -Descending { $_."Last Accessed" -as [datetime] } | select -first 1
$wishUrl = $wishLog | % {$_.URL.Substring(4)}
# clean up 
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force $tempPath
if ($wishUrl) {
    if (processWishUrl $wishUrl) {
        return
    }
}

Write-Host "Link not found! Make sure Genshin Impact is installed and open Wish History page at least once." -ForegroundColor Red
pause
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming.. yes i will be more careful in future...

Comment: @AhammedIrshad Glad to hear my answer was helpful. Don’t forgot to accept an answer for your questions, otherwise they will be considered “unresolved“ by the system. If you need further clarification, don’t hesitate to ask!